# When using Google Picker with drive.file scope, how long does access to selected files last?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have seen a few examples of folks using the Picker to select files and demonstrating that once the file is selected, it can be read, etc. But I am curious for how long the app's access to the file lasts once it has been picked. Is it indefinite? If not, how long does it last?

And as a corollary, how does the Drive API "know" that the file I'm reading was just selected by the picker? Does it keep track internally somehow? I don't see any kind of token that gets passed to the API request. But maybe I'm missing it.

Answer (score 0):

This might [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835869/how-to-create-file-picker-to-save-a-file-to-google-drive-using-rest-api?rq=1) your second question: "how does the Drive API "know" that the file I'm reading was just selected by the picker? Does it keep track internally somehow?"

> Google Drive REST API uses IDs to identify files and folders. The API
> does not provide file or directory pickers

> The file pickers identify files by URI and don't know anything about
> file IDs. Querying the files by name in order to get the id of the new
> file may fail as there may be duplicates in another or even the same
> folder.

But for your first question wherein

> how long the app's access to the file lasts once it has been picked.
> Is it indefinite? If not, how long does it last?

This doesn't seem to have any documentation for how long does Drive Picker provides access to the file, but I assume this is relevant to how Drive API authorizes requests stated here on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth)

Comment: I don't quite follow your gist here. I know that Drive uses file IDs and the Picker returns selected file objects that include the file's ID. My question is: when you query the Drive API using the returned ID, as in [this example](https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054#file-filepicker-js-L65), how does the Google API know that the user picked that file and thus granted access to it.